# Celery task in Flask for uploading and resizing images and storing it to Amazon S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, flask, celery

I'm trying to create a celery task for uploading and resizing an image before storing it to Amazon S3. But it doesn't work as expected. Without the task everything is working fine. This is the code so far:

stacktrace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../myVE/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 579, in _receive_callback
    decoded = None if on_m else message.decode()
  File "../myVE/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/base.py", line 147, in decode
    self.content_encoding, accept=self.accept)
  File "../myVE/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 187, in decode
    return decode(data)
  File "../myVE/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 74, in pickle_loads
    return load(BytesIO(s))
  File "../myVE/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 2595, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.stream, name)
  File "../myVE/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 2595, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.stream, name)
    ...
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

views.py

```
from PIL import Image

from flask import Blueprint, redirect, render_template, request, url_for

from myapplication.forms import UploadForm
from myapplication.tasks import upload_task


main = Blueprint('main', __name__)

@main.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    form = UploadForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        upload_task.delay(form.title.data, form.description.data,
                          Image.open(request.files['image']))
        return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
    return render_template('upload.html', form=form)
```

tasks.py

```
from StringIO import StringIO

from flask import current_app

from myapplication.extensions import celery, db
from myapplication.helpers import resize, s3_upload
from myapplication.models import MyObject


@celery.task(name='tasks.upload_task')
def upload_task(title, description, source):
    stream = StringIO()
    target = resize(source, current_app.config['SIZE'])
    target.save(stream, 'JPEG', quality=95)
    stream.seek(0)
    obj = MyObject(title=title, description=description, url=s3_upload(stream))
    db.session.add(obj)
    db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the lines of code you think you should go into a Celery task into a Celery task? Did it work?

Comment: Yes I have tried that. But it didn't work. I got:

"Can't decode message body: RuntimeError('maximum recursion depth extended while calling a Python object',)..."

venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 2595, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.stream, name)

Comment: I would recommend, then, that you modify this question to show the code that is actually causing your current trouble. Make sure to also include the stack trace in the question (you may need to cut out some of the middle, since it will probably be pretty long). Right now, your question is, "Could I make this a celery task", and the answer to that is yes, but that's not helpful for you. It is better you show us what you've tried and help you move forward in that respect.

Comment: @pkosel what was your workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are attempting to pass the entire uploaded file as part of the Celery message. I imagine that is causing you some trouble. I would recommend seeing if you can save the file to the web server as part of the view, then have the message (the "delay" argument) contain the filename rather than entire file's data. The task can then read the file in from the hard drive, upload to s3, then delete it locally.

Comment: Now I'm getting this error message: Working outsite of application context... Any idea? Thank you

Comment: @PhilippKosel: [Read this](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/appcontext/). Also, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478953/flask-0-10-mongo-working-outside-of-application-context). If you're still having problems, post a new question.

Answer (score 14):

I know this is a very old question, but I was struggling with passing the file's contents to the celery task. I would keep getting errors trying to follow what others have done. So I wrote this up, hoping it may help others in the future.

## TL;DR

- Send the file contents to the celery task with base64 encoding
- Decode the data in the celery task and use `io.BytesIO` for the stream

## Long answer

I was not interested in saving the image to disk and reading it again, so I wanted to pass the needed data to reconstruct the file in the background.

Trying to follow what others suggest, I kept getting encoding errors.
Some of the errors were:

- `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte`
- `TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes`

The `TypeError` was thrown by the `io.StringIO`. Trying to decode the data to get rid of the `UnicodeDecodeError` did not make much sense. As the data is binary in the first place, I tried to use a `io.BytesIO` instance, and that worked perfectly. The only thing I needed to do was to encode the file's stream with base64 and then I would be able to pass the content to the celery task.

## Code samples

*images.py*

```
import base64

file_.stream.seek(0) # start from beginning of file
# some of the data may not be defined
data = {
  'stream': base64.b64encode(file_.read()),
  'name': file_.name,
  'filename': file_.filename,
  'content_type': file_.content_type,
  'content_length': file_.content_length,
  'headers': {header[0]: header[1] for header in file_.headers}
}

###
# add logic to sanitize required fields
###

# define the params for the upload (here I am using AWS S3)
bucket, s3_image_path = AWS_S3_BUCKET, AWS_S3_IMAGE_PATH
# import and call the background task
from async_tasks import upload_async_photo 
upload_async_photo.delay(
  data=data,
  image_path=s3_image_path,
  bucket=bucket)
```

*async_tasks*

```
import base64, io
from werkzeug.datastructures import FileStorage

@celery.task
def upload_async_photo(data, image_path, bucket):
    bucket = get_s3_bucket(bucket) # get bucket instance
    try:
        # decode the stream
        data['stream'] = base64.b64decode(data['stream'])
        # create a BytesIO instance
        # https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o
        data['stream'] = io.BytesIO(data['stream'])
        # create the file structure
        file_ = FileStorage(**data)
        # upload image
        bucket.put_object(
                Body=file_,
                Key=image_path,
                ContentType=data['content_type'])
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```

### Edit

I also changed what content celery accepts and how it serializes data. To avoid having trouble passing the Bytes instance to the celery task, I had to add the following to my config:

```
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['pickle']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'pickle'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'pickle'
```

Comment: You could use `data = dict(**file.__dict__).update({"stream": base64.b64encode(file.stream)})` instead of creating a new dictionary and specifying each value.

Answer (score 1):

*I understand this is a very old post but just in case it helps someone - the best way forward in cases like this would be to download the image from an external source and then do the async operation.*

I could get a similar async problem working after fixing the serialization issue as suggested by @Obeyed (didn't need to change celery config though), but I eventually moved away from the solution **because file contents can potentially be very large and consume lot of resources in the message broker**.

@Mark Hildreth's approach would **not** be very helpful if you want to delegate the async task to a worker machine.

Perhaps a better approach in this case would have been uploading the original image synchronously and then asynchronously downloading, resizing and re-uploading the image to replace the original one.

Answer (score 1):

Passing files to a celery task is a problem because of file's serialization. It could be converted into bytes but it takes more memory than desired. It makes sense to share the file_path but if you are using docker images, they do not share the same paths.

So, my solution is to create shared volume between my api(web) container and celery container for them to have files shared.

```
api:
build: .
ports:
  - 8000:8000
volumes:
  - ./:/usr/src/app

celery_worker:
container_name: celery_worker
build: .
command: celery -A celery_worker.celery worker --loglevel=info
volumes:
  - .:/usr/src/app
```

My celery task is:

```
@celery.task
def test(file_path):
    print('Current directory in celery container is:' + os.getcwd())
    images_dir = os.getcwd()
    final_dir = os.path.join(images_dir,file_path)
    print(f'Filepath in celery task is : {final_dir}')
    with open(final_dir,"rb") as f:

        s3_client.upload_fileobj(f, bucket_name, file_path)
```

My code to call the task in fastapi endpoint is:

```
with open( file_path, "wb+" ) as file_object:
    file_object.write( uploaded_file.file.read() )
test.delay(file_path)
```

So, the best solution I found so far is to save the file in a shared volume between containers, pass the file path to the celery worker, upload the file to the s3 bucket and then remove the file in the volume.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I have just had the same problem. Accepted answer did not work for me (I'm using Docker instances so Celery does not have access to producers filesystem. Also, its slow to first save file to local filesystem).

My solution keeps the file in the RAM. It's therefore much faster. 
Only downside is if you need to handle large files (>1GB), then you need a server with a lot of RAM.

The doc_file is of type `werkzeug.datastructure.FileStorage` ([see docs here](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage))

Sending the file to celery worker:

```
entry.delay(doc_file.read(), doc_file.filename, doc_file.name, doc_file.content_length, doc_file.content_type, doc_file.headers)
```

Receiving the file:

```
from werkzeug.datastructures import FileStorage
from StringIO import StringIO

@celery.task()
def entry(stream, filename, name, content_length, content_type, headers):
    doc = FileStorage(stream=StringIO(stream), filename=filename, name=name, content_type=content_type, content_length=content_length)
    # Do something with the file (e.g save to Amazon S3)
```

Comment: Is there any other workarounds besides this way? There is no setting in celery that can take file?

Comment: After follwing your code, I was getting the following error:  `EncodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte`

Comment: Please try with another file.

Comment: If I were to do this in ipython for testing. How should I be loading entry.delay? how should doc_file.read() be loaded ? Do I just open('filename?')

Comment: Tried other files and getting same error. It has something to do with the doc_file.read()

Comment: are you supposed to use io.StringIO or just StringIO?